# How to clear everything from the view when changing to new route in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

So I have a set of navigation buttons, when a user clicks on any of the navigation, they are directed to another page, but the view of the previous page is shown with the view of the new page that the user has been directed.

For example, lets say I have 2 buttons:

`NMS` - when a user clicks on `NMS`, it is directed to `/NMS` page
`Informatics` - When a user goes to `/NMS` page, they see `Informatics` button.
'/Modules' - When the user clicks on Informatics button, they need to be directed to `modules` page with only modules view showing, not the informatics.

Here's a plunker to explain my issue
http://plnkr.co/edit/WvvCDwIind2QQXY88lay?p=preview

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have several routes from your primary `router-outlet`.

What you have now, is a primary `router-outlet` containing another one which has 2 routes.

Since your first `router-outlet` is rendering a view corresponding to a path, and you tell your secondary `router-outlet` to switch between several views, the view from the first outlet will not change, and therefore you will still have your current issue.